# Imgur API Commercial vs Free

Tags: imgur

I'm working on an app that, as one component, accesses the imgur API. I'm trying to work out if it is considered "Commercial" based on three separate possible models. As you can understand, as the sole developer, I'm just a hobby programmer and I want to know if I can build this without a heavy monthly bill from imgur.

From the imgur API doc page;

> Your application is commercial if you're making any money with it (which includes in-app advertising), if you plan on making any money with it, or if it belongs to a commercial organization.

What does that mean in these scenarios:

1. If I'm building an application that as a component of it uses the imgur API, that is not paid for, does not have any ongoing costs, but has a Patreon/GoFundMe/KoFi account attached to it to support development, is that considered "Commercial" here?
2. If I build the app, but charge a flat $5 for it, and no advertisement/in-app-purchases, is this considered commercial?
3. If I build the app, do not charge for it, do not post ads, but accept one-off donations towards developmnent, is this considered commercial as per the above?

Answer (score 0):

> If I'm building an application that as a component of it uses the
>   imgur API, that is not paid for, does not have any ongoing costs, but
>   has a Patreon/GoFundMe/KoFi account attached to it to support
>   development, is that considered "Commercial" here?

Possibly. Donations can very well be considered a source of income. In addition, you need to look at the second part of the Imgur ToS that you quoted:

> plan on making any money with it, or if it belongs to a commercial
>   organization.

Will the app remain free forever after a limited period of development?

> If I build the app,
>   but charge a flat $5 for it, and no advertisement/in-app-purchases, is
>   this considered commercial?

Yes, this can be considered commercial. Because you're charging money for the app.

> If I build the app, do not charge for it,
>   do not post ads, but accept one-off donations towards developmnent, is
>   this considered commercial as per the above?

This is very similar to the first scenario.

The important thing to understand is that there is a great deal of latitude in enforcing the ToS. This is both to ensure the convenience of users, and also to ensure that Imgur's services aren't abused. One of the statements in their ToS states something to the effect of "Don't use us as your CDN". It would seem that is what you're thinking of doing. Unless your app is for a demonstrably social/charitable purpose like curing cancer or world hunger, Imgur might just as well choose to enforce the ToS. Don't risk it. Go for a paid service (Imgur's or another).

To be really sure, one can directly contact Imgur with a link to the app and check with them.